# -endIn Service while Service started

Tags: windows, service, windows-xp, vmware, windbg

WinDbg always prints "-endin service while service started". I just don't know why.

[image: WinDbg Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, WinDbg will print everything that goes to the debug output, i.e. [OutputDebugString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of Windows API or [Debug.WriteLine()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in .NET.

To me, the output looks exactly like some debug output of the program and is not specific to WinDbg.

To confirm this, you could run the application without debugger and use [SysInternals DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/debugview.aspx) and check if you can see the same messages there.

Comment: thanks for your help! you are right!  It is not specific to WinDbg, I used DebugView to check it, it prints "service started!!! -end \n in Service while"

Comment: one more question, do you know anything about these strings? I guess it's  a program backup about service and do a while control struct.

Comment: @DsttanE: I'm sorry, I've never seen those messages before. You could put a breakpoint (`bp`) on `OutputDebugString`. When it stops at the breakpoint, you can see the callstack (`k`) and find out where it comes from

Comment: Hello, I put a bp on OutputDebugString, it doesn't work well. I found that when I use DebugView, it tells the PID about that process, so I found the process with Process Explorer, the process is svchost.exe and it is linked by C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe. it should be normal. I just want to tell you about this and maybe other guys can get help from this

Comment: @DsttanE: that would perfectly match the message. `svchost.exe` is hosting Windows services. If there is a custom service running with a debug build of the DLL, such output makes sense. To find out which service produces those messages, you can start/stop services. From the command line arguments of svchost you should get some information about the services hosted by the process.